# Deleting user sessions remotely in CakePHP

Tags: php, session, cakephp

In my CakePHP 2.4 app (using AuthComponent), I've got a `banned` field on my User model, which bans a user. If the user tries to log in, it checks for that field, and if they're banned, they get an error.

However, this doesn't work for users that are currently logged-in. **How do I remotely destroy a users' session, thereby logging them out?**

Theoretically, this could be logic I could put in `beforeSave`:

```
public function beforeSave(){
    if($this->data['banned'] == 1){
        // Logic to destroy session goes here
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with CakePHP, but assuming it's using the normal PHP session system, you would need to delete the session file on the disk. Alternatively you can check if the user is banned each time the user is loaded from the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ll need to use the database for sessions: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#database-sessions

Then on callback or signal `beforeSave` of user model, somehow you need to find out the session id of banned user and then delete it or clear the session value for that particular entry.

In my case, I have user id `5d76xxxx` and JSON structure as mentioned below

s:2:"id";s:8:"5d76xxxx"

Get the session ID first:

> SELECT * FROM  `cake_sessions` where data like '%s:2:"id";s:8:"5d76xxxx"%'

Then Update it or delete it

> UPDATE  `cake_sessions` SET  `data` = '' where id = 'e24a2120ff67fxxxxxxd7946f4e3'

I hope you got the logic!

Comment: I can achieve it without database session ?

Comment: nope somehow you need to keep track of session id and user id mapping, so using that you can delete or clear session for particular user id

Comment: If you want to delete them you can do it immediately via DELETE FROM  cake_sessions where data like '%s:2:"id";s:8:"5d76xxxx"%'

Answer (score 1):

You can check banned field of a user in beforeFilter  of AppController

The code might be something like this

```
$user = ClassRegistry::init('User');

$userId=$this->Auth->user('id');
$userInfo=$user->findById($userId);
if($userInfo['banned'] == 1){
$this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
```

Comment: Please do not instantiate models directly, that's a no-go! Use `Controller::loadModel()` or `ClassRegistry::init()`!

Comment: @FazalMohammad no need to search user again, because all the data about the user are available through ```$this->Auth->user()```
, as I wrote below in answer.

Comment: @Salines as you need to retrieve banned field value from database you cant use your User information containing by Auth in session. Becauase session User information have backdated banned value ($userInfo['banned']==0)

Comment: You're right, I totally forgot about that fact. I apologize. I'm too tired to properly thought.